# What is the way to verify eip 2535 proxy contracts with ethercan when deploying with foundry script?

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, forge

I used the --verify command but it doesn't show verified on etherscan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out:

Here is my script to deploy:

`forge script script/ScriptFile.s.sol:ScriptContractName --rpc-url https://goerli.infura.io/v3/**infuraAPI** --broadcast --verify -vvvv --ffi`

Then, I went here and entered the center diamond address: https://goerli.etherscan.io/proxyContractChecker?a=0x07865c6e87b9f70255377e024ace6630c1eaa37f

I hit verify and the contract now has read and write functionality on etherscan.  Pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to verify the contracts with Foundry. In my case, I solved the problem with the flag --flatten and paying attention to the params compiler version, nr runs, etc..
Hope it helps

Comment: were you using a proxy or just regular contract deployment?

Comment: a proxy and a implementation too